# very fast look up's in Perl : re-loading hash values possible?

Tags: perl, hash

I have about  100 million rows such as:

```
A : value of A
B : value of B
|
|
|
Z : value of Z  upto 100 million unique entries
```

Currently each time I run my program I load the entire file as a hash which takes some time. During the run time I need access to value of A,B given I know A,B etc.

I am wondering if I can make a hash once and store it as a binary data structure or index the file. What would be possible in in perl with least programming.

Thanks!
-Abhi

Comment: `perl -e'++$h{$_} for 1..100_000_000;'` takes 7 seconds for me. That's actually pretty fast. I think your code might be slow for you because you're running out of memory and thus resorting to using virtual memory. The best solution for you is probably one that doesn't require you to load the entire dataset into memory (e.g. a database solution).

Comment: you are right while using Storable module I figured out I am hitting memory limits. In the production dataset I have 500 rows. I think I need to go to DB based solution.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest an on-disk key/value database. Due to Perl's [tie function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html), they can be used identically to normal, in-memory hashes. They'll be faster than Perl's hashes for reading/writing if your hash is very large, and they support saving/loading to disk automatically.

[BerkeleyDB](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?BerkeleyDB) is an old favourite:

```
use BerkeleyDB;
# Make %db an on-disk database stored in database.dbm. Create file if needed
tie my %db, 'BerkeleyDB::Hash', -Filename => "database.dbm", -Flags => DB_CREATE
    or die "Couldn't tie database: $BerkeleyDB::Error";

$db{foo} = 1;            # get value
print $db{foo}, "\n";    # set value
for my $key (keys %db) {
    print "$key -> $db{$key}\n";  # iterate values
}

%db = ();  # wipe
```

Changes to the database are automatically saved to disk and will persist through multiple invocations of your script.

Check the perldoc for options, but the most important are:

```
# Increase memory allocation for database (increases performance), e.g. 640 MB
tie my %db, 'BerkeleyDB::Hash', -Filename => $filename, -CacheSize => 640*1024*1024;

# Open database in readonly mode
tie my %db, 'BerkeleyDB::Hash', -Filename => $filename, -Flags => DB_RDONLY;
```

A more complex but much faster database library would be [Tokyo Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/), and there are of course many other options (this is Perl after all...)

Comment: I guess I will have to use DB based method due to memory. I was  trying to initialize the BerkeleyDB env but the script is giving me error: cannot open environment No such file or directory : Code here `$berkeleyDB_env = new BerkeleyDB::Env
       -Cachesize =>$cacheSize
       or die "cannot open environment $BerkeleyDB::Error \n"; `  I am not sure why the code is not getting formatted...sorry about that

Comment: @ rjh : Also can I tie hash reference to a BerkeleyDB. I want to get more fancy in my data structure. Would like something like following $a->{$b}->{$c}->{$d}=e . I tired using `BerkeleyDB::Btree but i am getting an error `Can't locate object method "TIESCALAR" via package "BerkeleyDB::Btree"`

Comment: Abhi: not sure why you are making a `BerkeleyDB::Env` object? But if you add `-Flags => DB_CREATE`, it will work. For your other question - these databases only support strings for keys and values, so you will need to use `Storable` to `freeze` data structures before putting them into the database, and then `thaw` them when you pull them back out.

Comment: I am seeing a significant lag (about 1 million hash records are created in 1 hour compared to 250 million hash records created in memory in 15 mins) in the creation of BerkeleyDB file on disk compared to loading the data in memory. Does this sounds realistic ?

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) - it should do what you want and is extremely simple to use:

```
use Storable;
store \%table, 'file';
$hashref = retrieve('file');
```

This only helps if your program is actually limited by CPU speed, of course. Since your data structure is very simple, you may be parsing it faster than you can read it from disk. Storable isn't going to help you much in that case.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a core module, i.e. it comes included with Perl.

Comment: cool thanks .. I do have some parsing overhead which I dint include in here. Storable is great

Comment: And how does that save any time? A 100,000,000 entry hash will take the same time to create Whether `perl` or Storable creates it.

Comment: While creating a hash I am doing a lot of string manipulation extracting data from another text file so I can use a persistent DS with the help of Storable I can re-use it. Hopefully reloading the hash will take less time. However in my case as I mentioned I have to resort to DB based solution due to memory issues.

Comment: @ikegami: What makes you think that? Storable's core is written in C, why wouldn't it be faster than a pure Perl solution?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Tie::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html) as it is included in the core, as well as not loading your entire data structure into memory, but accessing individual records as needed from the disk.

Comment: Right idea (not loading everything into memory), but wrong implementation (Tie::File). Hashes are used to locate a record in constant time, whereas locating a record with Tie::File takes linear time. (+1 to cancel out undeserved -1)